# Moving from Romania to Sweden with a non-EU partner

Tags: resident-permit, family

I am a non-EU citizen, from Angola and I'm about to marry my Romanian girlfriend who she will come to my country soon to do the marriage papers here in my country, we have intentions to live in Sweden together and i was thinking what the best way to do that? Is it that she will go back to Romania and then apply for family reunion visa there and after go to lice together in Sweden? Or she should go to Sweden and directly apply for family reunion visa there? Keep in mind that in Romania she is qualified to be granted family reunion visa,  as she have a job and an apartment. And to be qualified in Sweden is hard as she have to go alone and live there and work for six months before i can apply for the visa to join her.

Comment: You are wrong about the six months. As an EU citizen, your wife will have the right to live in Sweden with her husband (you) under EU freedom of movement rules. All you have to do is prove that your marriage is genuine.  In general it is easier for EU citizens to bring their non-EU family to other EU countries than to their own country of citizenship.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, having resided together in Romania basically makes no difference as far as Sweden is concerned. It would be much easier to stay there long-time if your wife would get a job there (under EU rules, she could then sponsor your residence permit without any other requirement and certainly without any six-month waiting period) but in any case, there is no point in using Romania as a “stepping stone”, if your goal is to go to Sweden.

Comment: The wife doesn't need a job to bring the OP to Sweden; she would only need to have employment (or to qualify otherwise) for them to be able to stay longer than 90 days.

Comment: @phoog Yes, true, but this is the expats website and the OP talks about living there so that's what I was implicitely addressing. Also, there are other ways to qualify but having a job is easiest.

Comment: My point is that it's not necessary for Sam to wait for his wife to find a job before moving to Sweden.  They could move to Sweden together, whereupon she could start looking for work.  One might understand "she could then sponsor you" to imply otherwise.

Comment: @phoog Right, I tried to clarify that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I am an EEA national who went through this exact process in Sweden with my non-EU wife.

1. Your fiancee needs a job, admission to educational institution or private funds or income that shows that she can financially support both of you while living in Sweden. The job could even be in Denmark, Norway or Finland, and she can commute across the border to Sweden if geography makes this convenient. Of course, you could also live in any of those other countries. Anyway, the point is, she does not need a job *in Sweden*, she just needs to show that you and her have the money to live there.
2. After you are married, you need to find a place to live in Sweden.
3. You need a visa to enter Schengen, but as a family member of an EU national it should be issued free of charge and speedily. Apply at the nearest Swedish embassy or consulate. Attach proof that you are married, proof that you have the finances to live in Sweden and your housing contract. You should be a given a visa fast.
4. Once you have arrived in Sweden, go to the Swedish Migration Agency together with all your documents, and apply for EU residence cards. A card should be issued to you within six months.
5. After you have applied at the Migration Agency, if her job or studies are *within Sweden* you can both go to the Swedish Tax Agency and register there to get Swedish personal identification numbers (personnummer). Bring the receipt from your application at the Migration Agency and all the same documents. The personal identification number will be needed to get Swedish bank accounts, phone numbers, health care rights, etc. This number should be issued to both of you within 8 weeks maximum, assuming your wife works within Sweden.
6. Enjoy your life in Sweden! The rights of your EU wife and her family members (you and your possible future children) are quite strong in Sweden and the whole EEA!

Comment: Regarding step 3: Under freedom of movement, it's not necessary to have proof of finances nor a housing contract to get the visa.  They can get the visa before arranging any of that and then use the visa to go to Sweden together and find a job and an apartment.

Comment: @phoog Thank you, I did not know that that was not required when applying. When my wife applied, they asked for it. Thankfully, we already had it.

Comment: I don't know whether this applied to your case, but for someone already in Sweden for more than 3 months seeking to bring a family member into the country, they can ask for proof of employment (or enrollment, or "sufficient resources" independent of employment).  But for someone with a job they can't take the salary or wage level into account.  So I failed to note that for someone who hasn't been in Sweden for more than 3 months, your item 1 also does not apply.

Comment: @phoog Yeah I did not work in Sweden, I worked in Norway and commuted across the border. It's considered along the same lines as someone having private funds.

Comment: That makes much more sense in light of the freedom-of-movement directive.  I was dwelling on the point because the question expresses a concern about not being able to move to Sweden together, but the directive explicitly provides a right to do just that.

Comment: @phoog So they can go to Sweden together even before the EU national has a job there? And then they have 3 months for the EU national to get a job and then they can apply for residence cards?

Comment: Yes, precisely, under Art. 6 of [the directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616), *Right of residence for up to three months:* "1. Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of up to three months without any conditions or any formalities other than the requirement to hold a valid identity card or passport. 2. The provisions of paragraph 1 shall also apply to family members in possession of a valid passport who are not nationals of a Member State, accompanying or joining the Union citizen."